# Python class method chaining: Unexpected results with pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, method-chaining

While investigating method chaining within a python class for a project I'm starting, I encountered this unexpected error.  Wonder if someone can explain what might be happening in `method3()` below with the error thrown by the commented-out code which calculates `df['col6']` using `df['col5']` ... for some reason any reference to `col5` seems to throw errors.

```
import pandas as pd


class mchain:

def __init__(self, df):

    self._df = df

@property
def df(self):
    return self._df

def method1(self, msg):
    print(msg)
    self.df['col4'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col1']+x['col3'], axis=1) 
    return self

def method2(self, msg):
    print(msg)
    self.df['col5'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col4']**2, axis=1) 
    return self

def method3(self, msg):
    print(msg)
    self.df['col6'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col4']*2, axis=1) 
    #self.df['col6'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col5']*2, axis=1) 
    print(self.df.columns)
    return self

def method4(self):
    print(self.df.head().to_string())
    return self


if __name__ == '__main__':

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'col3': [3,3,2,4,6]})
a = mchain(df)
print(a.method1('beginning').method3('end'))
print(a.method1('beginning').method2('middle').method3('end').method4())
```

Here's the error traceback when I uncomment the code in method3 ..

```
(calculator) [Mon Sep 20 11:20:18]:Project python3 ./utils/methodchainingtest.py 
beginning
end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'col5'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zzz/Documents/repos/Project/./utils/methodchainingtest.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(a.method1('beginning').method3('end'))
  File "/Users/zzz/Documents/repos/Project/./utils/methodchainingtest.py", line 27, in method3
    self.df['col6'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col5']*2, axis=1) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7768, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 185, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 276, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 290, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "/Users/zzz/Documents/repos/Project/./utils/methodchainingtest.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    self.df['col6'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: x['col5']*2, axis=1) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'col5'
(calculator) [Mon Sep 20 11:34:31]:Project
```

Comment: Your first line calls `method3` without calling `method2` first (which is what defines `col5` that the commented line in `method3` assumes exists).

Comment: Oops!.  How did I manage to miss that.  Well that was easy.  Thanks!

Comment: if you want to write that as a solution, I would be happy to mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: I'm willing to stretch and call this a typo. :)